# If a word is repeated many times in a string, how can I count the number of repetitions of the word and their positions?

Tags: c++

If a word is repeated many times in a string, how can I count the number of repetitions of the word and their positions?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    string str2;
    getline(cin, str2);
    const char* p = strstr(str.c_str(), str2.c_str());
    if (p)
        cout << "'" << str2 << "' find in " << p - str.c_str();
    else
        cout << target << "not find \"" << str << "\"";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Use `string::find` and _not_ `strstr` in c++.

Comment: I wouldn't even do that. `std::stringstream` pushing back into a `std::vector`. Iterate over vector and count in a `std::map`.

Comment: I recommend using `std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>>`.  The first parameter is the word.  The second parameter is a vector of positions.

Answer (score -1):

Just off the top of my head, you could use `find()` within `std::string`. `find()` returns the first match of a substring within your string (or `std::string::npos` if there is no match), so you would need to loop until `find()` was not able to find any more matches of your string.

Something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {

    std::string largeString = "Some string with substrings";
    std::string mySubString = "string";
    
    int numSubStrings = 0;
    std::vector<size_t> locations;
    
    size_t found = 0;

    while(true) {
        found = largeString.find(mySubString, found+1);
        if (found != std::string::npos) {
            numSubStrings += 1;
            locations.push_back(found);
        }

        else {
            break; // there are no more matches
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d occurences of: \n%s \nin \n%s\n", numSubStrings, mySubString.c_str(), largeString.c_str());
}
```

Which outputs:

```
There are 2 occurences of: 
string 
in 
Some string with substrings
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below uses a lot of the Standard Library to do common things for us. I use a file to collect words into one large string. I then use a `std::stringstream` to separate the words on whitespace and I store the individual words in a `std::vector` (an array that manages its size and grows when needed). In order to get a good count of the words, punctuation and capitalization must also be removed, this is done in the `sanitize_word()` function. Finally, I add the words to a map where the word is the key, and the `int` is the count of how many times that word occurred. Finally, I print the map to get a complete word count.

The only place I directly did any string parsing is in the sanitize function, and it was done using the aptly named erase/remove idiom. Letting the Standard Library do the work for us when possible is much simpler.

Locating where a word occurs also becomes trivial after they've been separated and sanitized.

Contents of input.txt:

```
I must not fear. Fear is the mind-killer. Fear is the little-death that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me. And when it has gone past, I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone, there will be nothing. Only I will remain.
```

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Removes puncuation marks and converts words to all lowercase
std::string sanitize_word(std::string word) {
  word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(),
                            [punc = std::string(".,?!")](auto c) {
                              return punc.find(c) != std::string::npos;
                            }),
             word.end());
  for (auto& c : word) {
    c = std::tolower(c);
  }

  return word;
}

int main() {
  // Set up
  std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
  if (!fin) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening file...\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::string phrases;
  for (std::string tmp; std::getline(fin, tmp);) {
    phrases += tmp;
  }
  fin.close();

  // Words are collected, now the part we care about
  std::stringstream strin(phrases);
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  for (std::string tmp; strin >> tmp;) {
    words.push_back(tmp);
  }

  for (auto& i : words) {
    i = sanitize_word(i);
  }

  // std::map's operator[]() function will create a new element in the map if it
  // doesn't already exist
  std::map<std::string, int> wordCounts;
  for (auto i : words) {
    ++wordCounts[i];
  }

  for (auto i : wordCounts) {
    std::cout << i.first << ": " << i.second << '\n';
  }

  // Now we'll do code to locate a certain word, "fear" for this example
  std::string wordToFind("fear");
  auto it = wordCounts.find(wordToFind);
  std::cout << "\n\n" << it->first << ": " << it->second << '\n';
  std::vector<int> locations;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    if (words[i] == wordToFind) {
      locations.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Found at locations: ";
  for (auto i : locations) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
and: 2
be: 1
brings: 1
eye: 1
face: 1
fear: 5
gone: 2
has: 2
i: 5
inner: 1
is: 2
it: 2
its: 1
little-death: 1
me: 2
mind-killer: 1
must: 1
my: 1
not: 1
nothing: 1
obliteration: 1
only: 1
over: 1
pass: 1
past: 1
path: 1
permit: 1
remain: 1
see: 1
that: 1
the: 4
there: 1
through: 1
to: 2
total: 1
turn: 1
when: 1
where: 1
will: 5


fear: 5
Found at locations: 3 4 8 20 50
```